# What is the term for a word/name that describes the function?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the term for a word/name that describes the function?

One example is *dishwasher*, which is a machine that does exactly what the name suggests- it washes dishes.

Comment: The antonyms for 'misnomer' I've found ('apt name' / 'fitting name' / 'appropriate name' ...) are not single words. 'The aptly named _dishwasher_'. One could use irony: 'The imaginatively named _dishwasher_'.

Comment: There's also _garbage compactor_, a similar Object-Verb compound, though usually spelled with a space. It's defined as 'a machine that turns 50 pounds of garbage into 50 pounds of garbage". Of course, _pony ride_ and _snake bite_ are also noun compounds that describe the function, but it's a different function each time - _pony_ is the Object of _ride_ but _snake_ is the Subject of _bite_.

Comment: [Agent nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/367704/191178)? Or are you talking about a broader category of nouns?

Comment: The topic is machine names.

Comment: I genuinely can't think of such a term in common English usage. The other commenter's "aptly named" is about as close as I think you'll come -- a descriptive adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: A dishwasher has a *descriptive name*. I wouldn't expect there to be a commonly-used term for this, although some philosopher may have coined something. Although once you know what a fish is, "fish" is as descriptive as "dishwasher".

Comment: This might be a better question for [linguistics.se]. I'm sure words like this exist in all languages, it hardly seems specific to English.

Comment: A dish washer was a person before it was a machine.  Now people are still called dishwashers but they may operate the machines more than wash the dishes.  Are you looking for just machine names?  Or millers, for example?

Answer (score 1):

An [autological](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) word describes itself or is self-refential.  "Noun" is a noun, for example.  Homological is another term. Visible can be seen  here and it is polysyllabic. Writing is writing*.

---

*Mileage may vary (argument for cursive).

Comment: "Dishwasher" isn't a dishwasher, though.

Comment: @user888379 - clarify. As far as I'm aware, a dishwasher is indeed... a dishwasher.

Comment: What are the extra lines for? Is it something clever that I'm missing?

Comment: @Heartspring The word "dishwasher" isn't itself used to wash dishes.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest general term I can suggest is *descriptor*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/descriptor)
> *descriptor*:
> a word or phrase used to describe or refer to something

It is a word that has come into use since about 1960 (according to the google ngram usage graph).

Hence, "dishwasher" is the descriptor of a machine that washes dishes. I cannot think of a descriptor that does not describe the function of the thing it refers to; if it did not describe the thing it would not be a descriptor. Therefore I suggest the word may suit your purpose.

Comment: I think he's looking for something more specific, where the descriptor is formed by turning a descriptive phrase into a word.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps, which is why I refer to the “nearest general term”; it may suffice but it may not. Let’s hope that the community contributes something better.